# Minimize Node js application .js files?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

We have developed a desktop application using node webkit and it works fine. My only doubt is that, do we need to perform minification on the .js files written as part of node js server component. We usually perform minification on the javascript written mainly for UI view to reduce payload during loading of related javascripts of the HTML and also to hide coding information in the scripts so that its hard to modify.

So do we need to perform similar kind of concatenation and minification process on the node js server side .js files and then share the node webkit executable to the Customer. Without minification of node js files, the application works perfectly fine.

So, going back to my question -- Do we need to perform javascripts concatenation and minification for node js application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minification is generally to save bandwidth when downloading script files over the internet, so there isn't any real point to minifying your node.js files on your server if they aren't served anywhere.

I really doubt your server's storage needs to save a few kilobytes.

Comment: Wouldn't it go a little faster if you don't have to reload a few kb on each hit to the server?!